# How do you connect to the internet in backtrack 5 R2

Tags: internet, backtrack, wicd

I have recently installed backtrack 5 r2 so it dual-boots alongside windows. However for some reason I'm finding it difficult to make a wired connection using wicd. I know that the connection itself works because it's fine on windows. I also don't have (never had) a static IP. What steps do I have to follow to setup a such connection?

Comment: backtrack is not for the casual user. If you're not familiar with using `dhcpd` and `ifconfig` from the command line without help then perhaps backtrack isn't for you. Maybe try Ubuntu instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this error as well, following the instructions on backtrack wiki you can solve the issue with the nektwork connection, the principal problem is the WICD that doesn't start and you cannot connect automaticaly, but when you start it for the first time it works every reboot

```
/etc/init.d/networking start
dpkg-reconfigure wicd
update-rc.d -f wicd defaults
```

And this whould do the trick, also I reccomend to you that visit and suscribe on the backtrack forum, but as @bahamat said, if you are new on linux world, try first ubuntu or another distro like mint.

the link for the answer and also the wiki:

http://www.backtrack-linux.org/wiki/index.php/Basic_Usage